# How to accept None for integer type field

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-restplus

I have an endpoint to update a company model, one of the fields is "post_box" that is an integer, this is an optional parameter that feaults to null. So far, so good. But, I need to be able to set this to null so that the user can remove any value the post_box may have. The frontend sends post_box: None if it is blank in the number input field i use for that. The response is {post_box: "None is not of type 'integer'"}

I know None is not an integer, how do I do this correctly?

Company model

```py
class Company(db.Model):
    """ Company Model for storing company related details """
    __tablename__ = "company"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    public_id = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    company_name = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    organisation_number = db.Column(db.BigInteger, unique=True)
    street_name = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=False, nullable=False)
    post_code = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=False, nullable=False)
    post_area = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False, nullable=False)
    post_box = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=False, nullable=True, default=None)
    longitude = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=False, nullable=True, default=None)
    latitude = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=False, nullable=True, default=None)
    registered_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    customers = db.relationship("Customer", cascade="all,delete")
    projects = db.relationship("Project", cascade="all,delete")

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Name '{}'>".format(self.company_name).encode('utf-8')
```

Method to save company

```py
def save_new_company(data):
    company = Company.query.filter_by(organisation_number=data['organisation_number']).first()
    if not company:
        user = User.query.filter_by(public_id=data['user_public_id']).one()
        new_company = Company(
            public_id=str(uuid.uuid4()),
            company_name=data['company_name'],
            organisation_number=data['organisation_number'],
            street_name=data['street_name'],
            post_code=data['post_code'],
            post_area=data['post_area'],
            registered_on=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
            user_id=user.id,
        )
        try:
            if data['post_box']:
                new_company.post_box = None
        except KeyError:
            pass
        try:
            if data['longitude']:
                new_company.longitude = data['longitude']
        except KeyError:
            pass
        try:
            if data['latitude']:
                new_company.latitude = data['latitude']
        except KeyError:
            pass

        save_changes(new_company)
        response_object = {
            'status': 'success'
        }
        return response_object, 200

    else:
        response_object = {
            'status': 'fail',
            'message': 'Company already exists.',
        }
        return response_object, 409
```

Snippet from the relevant part of the controller

```py
@api.expect(_company, validate=True)
    @api.response(201, 'Company successfully created.')
    @api.doc('create a new company')
    def post(self):
        """Creates a new Company """
        data = request.json
        result = save_new_company(data=data)
        return result
```

And some more relevant stuff:

```py
class CompanyDto:
    api = Namespace('company', description='company related operations')
    company = api.model('company', {
        'public_id': fields.String(description='company public identifier'),
        'company_name': fields.String(required=True, description='Company name'),
        'organisation_number': fields.Integer(required=True, description='Organisation number'),
        'street_name': fields.String(required=True, description='Company street name'),
        'post_code': fields.Integer(required=True, description='Company post code'),
        'post_area': fields.String(required=True, description='Company post area'),
        'post_box': fields.Integer(required=False, nullable=True, default=None, description='Company post box'),
        'longitude': fields.String(required=False, description='Company longitude'),
        'latitude': fields.String(required=False, description='Company latitude'),
        'user_public_id': fields.String(required=True, description='User identifier'),
    })
```

The error returned:

post_box: "None is not of type 'integer'"

Comment: if you know it is an integer, then why would you want its default value to be None? I think it makes more sense to have it's default value set to -1 or something that you would never expect in your dataset

Comment: Ah, that is true. Not every company has a post box so I figured None would be appropriate, but I suppose -1 or even 0 would work. Did not think of that. :-)

Comment: this is the answer if somebody still needs it  here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60538873/3693863