# How to accept None for String type field when using Flask-RESTPlus

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restplus

---

I am just starting develop with flask-restplus and I am not a native speaker,

but I will try to describe my question as clear as I can.

I know there is a `fields` module in [flask](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.3/fields.html) that help us define and filter response data type,

such as String, Integer, List and so on.

**Is there any way to allow NULL / None when using fields module?**

the following is my code that using field module to catch the value,

```
add_group = api.model(
        "add_group",
        {"team_groups": fields.List(fields.Nested(api.model("team_groups", {
            "name": fields.String(example="chicago bulls", description="name of add group"),
            "display_name": fields.String(example="bulls", description="display name of add group")})))})
```

and if the data type of `display_name` is not String, there would be the following error raised,

```
{
    "errors": {
        "team_groups.0.display_name": "123 is not of type 'string'"
    },
    "message": "Input payload validation failed"
}
```

**what I want is when entering display_name, I can enter `bulls` or `None`**

---

It seems few of the reference data / questions can be found, and I only found [one result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56840335/how-to-accept-none-for-integer-type-field) related

to my question, but eventually converting as non-null value to solve the issue.

if there is any part of my question not much clear,

please let me know, thank you.

the following is my develop environment:

`flask-restplus     0.13.0`
`Python 3.7.4`
`postman 7.18.1`

---

**The following is my updated code:**

```py
from flask_restplus import Namespace, fields

class NullableString(fields.String):
    __schema_type__ = ['string', 'null']
    __schema_example__ = 'nullable string'

class DeviceGroupDto:
    api = Namespace("device/group", description="device groups")
    header = api.parser().add_argument("Authorization", location="headers", help="Bearer ")

    get_detail_group = api.model(
        "getdetail",
        {"team_groups": fields.List(fields.String(required=True,
                                                  description="team group id to get detail", example=1))})

    add_group = api.model(
        "add_group",
        {"team_groups": fields.List(fields.Nested(api.model("team_groups", {
            "name": fields.String(example="chicago bulls", description="name of add group"),
            "display_name": NullableString(attribute='a')})))})
```

**if I input the following payload: (by postman)**

```
{
    "team_groups": [
        {
            "name": "chicago bulls",
            "display_name": null
        }
    ]
}
```

**It still returns:**

```
{
    "errors": {
        "team_groups.0.display_name": "None is not of type 'string'"
    },
    "message": "Input payload validation failed"
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can create a child class and use it instead of default ones, which will accept None as well

```
class NullableString(fields.String):
    __schema_type__ = ['string', 'null']
    __schema_example__ = 'nullable string'
```

So your code will look like

```
{ "property": NullableString(attribute=value)}
```

Additionally you can visit the issue [github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/179](https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/179)

Comment: Thanks your recommendation, I think creating a child class from `fields.String` is a  good direction, but I still can't pass null to the NullableString class, according to my updated code (on my post), does I miss the point ?

Comment: I think you have done it correctly, it should work correctly, i use it  with `flask_restplus=0.12.1` and this is the way we have to do it.

Comment: Updated to `flask-resplus==0.13.0` and then  use @Stefan Answer. It will worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

if some of your fields are optional then make `required=False`

```
add_group = api.model(
        "add_group",
        {"team_groups": fields.List(fields.Nested(api.model("team_groups", {
            "name": fields.String(example="chicago bulls", description="name of add group"),
            "display_name": fields.String(example="bulls", description="display name of add group", required=False)})))})
```

Comment: Thanks for kindly response,

but after trying this, it still happens the similar error like
`"team_groups.0.display_name": "123 is not of type 'string'"`

It looks like fields module still didn't allow null to pass

Answer (score 1):

Here's slightly evolved approach that I use. It lets you have fields of any type as nullable.

```py
def nullable(fld, *args, **kwargs):
    """Makes any field nullable."""

    class NullableField(fld):
        """Nullable wrapper."""

        __schema_type__ = [fld.__schema_type__, "null"]
        __schema_example__ = f"nullable {fld.__schema_type__}"

    return NullableField(*args, **kwargs)

employee = api.model(
  "Employee",
  {
    "office": nullable(fields.String),
    "photo_key": nullable(fields.String, required=True),
  },
)
```